# Next predicate confusion

Tags: prolog

I'm in the process of learning prolog, I'm currently writing a next predicate for a game which is really simple.

you have a list [1,0,1,0,0,1] A legal move is move a 1 to a zero position, the 1 can only move right to the first position containing 0, but it is allowed to jump over other values if necessary.

firstly I wrote a predicate to change the value 0 to 1:

```
flip_first_zero([0|Tail], [1|Tail]).
```

simple enough, now I'm trying to find the legal moves, I will try to explain my thought process:

```
next([],[],[]).
next([Head|Tail], Rest, Out):-
    flip_first_zero([Head|Tail],List1),
    append(Rest,List1,Out).

next([Head|Tail], [Head|Rest], List):-
    next(Tail,Rest, List).
```

an example `[1,0,0,1,1,1,0]` the output should be `[0,1,0,1,1,1,0] ; [1,0,0,0,1,1,1]; [1,0,0,1,0,1,1] ; [1,0,0,1,1,0,1].`

[**1**,0,0,1,1,1,0] -> [0,**1**,0,1,1,1,0]

[1,0,0,**1**,1,1,0] -> [1,0,0,0,1,1,**1**]

[1,0,0,1,**1**,1,0] -> [1,0,0,1,0,1,**1**]

[1,0,0,1,1,**1**,0] -> [1,0,0,1,1,0,**1**]

So how I've understood this is, I loop through removing the head each time by conserving this in Rest so I can append it back on after.

Am I approaching this wrong?

Comment: Regarding your second question: you put `0` in both clauses - just change it to `1` in the first one and it will work as expected.

Comment: ahhh I'm an idiot hah, thank you @Steven

Comment: Regarding your main question, I'm also confused about what you're trying to do with the second argument. I don't think you need it at all - just prepend the `Head` to the output list if you want to leave i unchanged.

Comment: That works but its adding an extra 1 rather than swapping @Steven

Comment: *A legal move is move a 1 to a zero position, the 1 can only move right to the first position containing 0, but it is allowed to jump over other values if necessary.*  By "other values" I suppose you mean 1 values, since you said a 1 can only move to the first 0 position? Please provide a couple of full examples. What does the transform of `[1,0,1,0,0,1]` look like?

Comment: *I have another question, doesn't necessarily need an answer just I am very curious*. If this is a different question, either (a) you want an answer and you should ask it as a separate question on stackoverflow, or (b) if you don't want the answer, asking it kind of clutters the current question.

Comment: Okay no worries I'll remove the second part, for an example [1,0,0,1,1,1,0] the output should be [0,1,0,1,1,1,0] ; [1,0,0,0,1,1,1]; [1,0,0,1,0,1,1] ; [1,0,0,1,1,0,1] @lurker

Comment: Great example. So each solution is a single move of a 1. Why not edit your question and add the example there? Then others can easily see it.

Comment: How did you come up with `[1,0,0,0,1,1,1]` or `[1,0,0,1,0,1,1]` as a solution if you only moved a single 1 after the first subsequent 0? Or if you can really do more than one move for a solution to be valid, then there are more solutions than you are showing.

Comment: [1,0,0,0,1,1,1] is from the 1 jumping over consecutive 1's that is legal @lurker

Comment: I still don't see how you took a single 1 from `[1,0,0,1,1,1,0]`, and inserted it after the first seen 0 after that 1, and then obtained `[1,0,0,0,1,1,1]`. Which 1 did you pick to move in that case? Maybe the description of a legal move isn't clear to me.

Comment: You can choose any 1 to move it doesn't have to be the left most 1 @lurker

Comment: Yes I got that. Which of the 1's did you choose to move in the example you are showing? I don't see how to start with `[1,0,0,1,1,1,0]`, choose just a single 1, and move it after the first seen 0 after that 1, and then get `[1,0,0,0,1,1,1]`. Can you tell me which single 1 you chose and where you moved it in that case? You can't go from `[1,0,0,1,1,1,0]` to `[1,0,0,0,1,1,1]` with a single move of a 1 as far as I can tell.

Comment: check my edit @lurker when the 1 is moved the original position of the 1 is changed to a 0. You can go from [1,0,0,1,1,1,0] to [1,0,0,0,1,1,1] because the second 1 going from left to right jumps over the other 1s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem has two pieces: (1) the location of a 1, (2) the location of the first 0 after finding the 1 so that the 1 can be placed in its new position. The Prolog solution will reflect this. Your initial attempt tries to handle everything in a single predicate, which I believe makes the task a little more difficult.

The base case is easy. It represents the smallest valid move.

```
move([1,0], [0,1]).
```

Then the recursive cases. These enforce at least 3 positions in the list since the trivial case of 2 positions is already handled by the base case, and it establishes mutual exclusion in the rules to avoid redundant solutions.

```
% If we're at a 0 (space), keep going
move([0,X1,X2|T], [0|R]) :-
    move([X1,X2|T], R).

% If we see a 1, we can move it, or we can leave it alone and move on
move([1,X1,X2|T], [0|R]) :-
    place([X1,X2|T], R).
move([1,X1,X2|T], [1|R]) :-
    move([X1,X2|T], R).

% Place the 1 at the first located 0 (space)
place([0|T], [1|T]).
place([1|T], [1|R]) :-
    place(T, R).
```

So to determine valid next positions from a starting position:

```
| ?-  move([1,0,0,1,1,1,0],R).

R = [0,1,0,1,1,1,0] ? a

R = [1,0,0,0,1,1,1]

R = [1,0,0,1,0,1,1]

R = [1,0,0,1,1,0,1]

(1 ms) no
| ?-
```

You can also determine what starting positions would lead to a particular next position:

```
| ?- move(S, [1,0,0,1,0,1,1]).

S = [1,0,0,1,1,0,1] ? a

S = [1,0,0,1,1,1,0]

S = [1,0,1,0,0,1,1]

no
```

---

This can also be done using a DCG:

```
move([0, 1]) --> [1, 0].
move([0|R]) --> see(0), move(R).
move([0|R]) --> see(1), place(R).
move([1|R]) --> see(1), move(R).

see(N), [X1, X2] --> [N, X1, X2].

place([1|T]) --> [0], seq(T).
place([1|R]) --> [1], place(R).

seq([]) --> [].
seq([X|Xs]) --> [X], seq(Xs).

| ?- phrase(move(R), [1,0,0,1,1,1,0]).

R = [0,1,0,1,1,1,0] ? a

R = [1,0,0,0,1,1,1]

R = [1,0,0,1,0,1,1]

R = [1,0,0,1,1,0,1]

no
| ?- phrase(move([1,0,0,1,0,1,1]), S).

S = [1,0,0,1,1,0,1] ? a

S = [1,0,0,1,1,1,0]

S = [1,0,1,0,0,1,1]

no
```

Answer (score 2):

One logical way to approach this: find what comes before a 1, then what comes after a 1 and before a 0, and a rest. Then, you need to swap the 1 and 0 so that you have Before 1, 0, after 1 before 0, 1, after 0.

Start small. First, to just split the list whenever you have a 1, so that you have `Before` and `After`, you can use `append/3` like this, using the list from your example:

```
?- append(Before, [1|After], [1,0,0,1,1,1,0]).
Before = [],
After = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0] ;
Before = [1, 0, 0],
After = [1, 1, 0] ;
Before = [1, 0, 0, 1],
After = [1, 0] ;
Before = [1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
After = [0] ;
false.
```

You already get the 4 solutions you expect. Now you need to look inside `After` to see where to put the `1` -- well, you need to put it right after the first 0. So let's split `After` on a 0, but just once:

```
?- append(Before, [1|After], [1,0,0,1,1,1,0]),
   once( append(Before0, [0|After0], After) ). 
Before = Before0, Before0 = [],
After = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
After0 = [0, 1, 1, 1, 0] ;
Before = [1, 0, 0],
After = [1, 1, 0],
Before0 = [1, 1],
After0 = [] ;
Before = [1, 0, 0, 1],
After = [1, 0],
Before0 = [1],
After0 = [] ;
Before = [1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
After = [0],
Before0 = After0, After0 = [] ;
false.
```

Now you have 3 pieces: one before the 1 called `Before`, one between the 1 and the first 0 called `Before0`, and a last piece after the first 0 called `After0`. You just need to put them back together: `Before`, 0, `Before0`, 1, `After0`. You can use the 2-argument `append/2` that takes a list of lists in the first argument:

```
?- append(Before, [1|After], [1,0,0,1,1,1,0]),
   once( append(Before0, [0|After0], After) ),
   append([Before, [0|Before0], [1|After0]], Result).
Result = [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0] ;
Result = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1] ;
Result = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1] ;
Result = [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1] ;
false.
```

(I left only the `Result` bindings to save space.)

I think you are done at this point.

Comment: Nice job s(X). I'm still having trouble understanding what the transformation is supposed to do. :-/

Comment: @lurker it is supposed to teach students something, presumably how to use Prolog ;-) seriously now, this question pops up somewhat regularly. I think it is about finding the next possible states in a game. Not sure what the rules of the game are, but I guess the list is a (one-dimensional) board, the 0s are empty spots, the 1s are things on the board, and a "next" move just moves a thing according to the rules described in the question.

Comment: Yeah, I was getting the general gist. The detailed rules of a move, though, were eluding me for some reason... Like what's the rule for moving a single 1 that results in `[1,0,0,1,1,1,0]` becoming `[1,0,0,0,1,1,1]`? I must have a mental block.

Comment: @lurker My understanding is that a thing moves to the right to the first empty spot. In the example you give, the 1 in position 4 moves to the first free spot, which is position 7.

Comment: @lurker ... which is also why there are no possible moves for `[0,1]` for example

Comment: I realize `[0,1]` would have no move. But if I move the 1 from position 4 (in `[1,0,0,1,1,1,0]`) to the first free position (defined as after the very first subsequent 0), wouldn't that be `[1,0,0,1,1,0,1]`? How does the 0 end up at position 4 as in `[1,0,0,0,1,1,1]`?

Comment: @lurker Again, in my understanding, you represent a one-dimensional board with _n_ fields as a list of length _n_. Then, you put "things" (all the same?) on the board, and mark with 1 every thing and with 0 every free spot: for position _x_, if there is a thing, `nth1(X, List, 1)`, otherwise `nth1(X, List, 0)`. Then, you _pick a thing_ and move it to the _first empty field to its right_.
This is just an analogy that works for me....

Comment: Ah ok, I think I get it. Sometimes I'm pretty slow.

Comment: @lurker I have seen the question before, that's why.... I tried to find previous questions and solutions but it seems those are as badly formulated as OP's question, so no luck. There should be "Homework overflow" site, Stackoverflow just doesn't work as it should for questions like this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, check out the answer I wrote

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for all the answers, this is how I did it:

```
flip_first_zero([0|L],[1|L]):-!.
flip_first_zero([X|L],[X|L1]):-
    flip_first_zero(L,L1).

next([1|L],[0|L1]):-
    flip_first_zero(L,L1).
next([X|L],[X|L1]):-
    next(L,L1).
```

Comment: This is more concise, but not as general as the solution I provided. For example, suppose you wanted to ask "what starting positions lead to move `[1,0,0,1,0,1,1]`?".  If you use the solution I provided, you can query `move(S, [1,0,0,1,0,1,1])` and get the correct results. Your solution produces results which are incorrect in that case, probably due to the reliance on cut (`!`) to make it concise.